# Airflow PostgresOperator (redshift database) autocommit doesn't work

Tags: transactions, amazon-redshift, airflow, autocommit

- Airflow: v1.10.3
- Redshift: v1.0.15896

I have a SQL statement that (re-)creates a schema and then creates a view within that schema.

The SQL statement looks as follows:

```
drop schema if exists my_schema CASCADE;
create schema my_schema;
create or replace view my_schema.my_view as select * from other_schema.table with no schema binding;
```

If I run above SQL statements via a client tool (eg DBeaver or Datagrip, in autocommit mode) everything works as expected and returns no errors.

However, when I run the same SQL statement via Airflow using the PostgresOperator, I always get the following error message:

```
[2020-05-25 15:03:49,155] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - schema "my_schema" does not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/postgres_operator.py", line 65, in execute
    self.hook.run(self.sql, self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 172, in run
    cur.execute(s)
ProgrammingError: schema "my_schema" does not exist
```

This is how I execute the SQL statement in my DAG:

```
[...]
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
[...]
PostgresOperator(
        task_id=task_id, postgres_conn_id="my_connection", sql=sql, autocommit=True
)
```

If I run "drop and re-create" first and the "create or replace view" in a second Operator, it works without an issue.

It also works if the schema already exists.

Hence I suspect that somehow, there is no commit happening although autocommit is set to True.

I already tried many things within the SQL statements, including

- wrapping the schema creation in a transaction using "begin;" and "end;" statements
- Adding a "COMMIT;" after the schema (re-) creation
- Adding "set AUTOCOMMIT TO ON ; "

but nothing helped so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post the `begin`, `end`, `commit` you have tried? I think having `begin; schema_creation; commit; end;` should've worked

Comment: Have you tried setting the queries in a list like sql=['drop', 'create', 'create or replace']?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. LuckyGuess: I tried several combinations and yours just now again to double check. Unfortunately, I get the same result. Javier López Tomás: That's a great suggestion! I wasn't aware of the ability to pass a list. I used str.split(";") to decompose the big sql string and pass each statement separately. Now it works like a charm! Thanks :-)